# Combining 3 SQL queries into 1

Tags: php, sql

Coming from a row in table A I need to get row in table B that gets a row in table C.
With my basic knowledge I put a query in a query in a query, but I assume there is a better way to do that?

```
<?php  $result = pg_query($dbconn, "
    SELECT sequence, w_homepage_package_id                            
    FROM adempiere.w_homepage_package
    WHERE sequence > 0
    ORDER BY sequence ASC
    "); // first QUERY
    while ($promo = pg_fetch_row($result)) { // first WHILE
        $id = $promo[1];    
        $produktfoto = pg_query($dbconn, "
        SELECT w_bilder_id 
        FROM adempiere.w_homepage_image 
        WHERE w_homepage_package_id = $id LIMIT 1"); // second QUERY
        while ($produktrow = pg_fetch_row($produktfoto)) { // second WHILE
            $bilderid = $produktrow[0];
            $bildurl = pg_query($dbconn, "
            SELECT w_bildurl 
            FROM adempiere.w_bilder 
            WHERE w_bilder_id = $bilderid LIMIT 1"); // third QUERY
            while ($bildpfad = pg_fetch_row($bildurl)) { // third WHILE
                echo $bildpfad[0];
            }
        }
    ;}                                  
    ?>
```

Comment: use join. check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct left join query (If I haven't forgotten anything)

```
SELECT * 
FROM  adempiere.w_homepage_package 
      LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_homepage_image 
             ON adempiere.w_homepage_package.w_homepage_package_id =  adempiere.w_homepage_image.w_homepage_package_id 
      LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_bilder 
             ON adempiere.w_homepage_image.w_bilder_id = adempiere.w_bilder.w_bilder_id 
WHERE  sequence > 0 
ORDER  BY sequence ASC
```

To understand JOIN think about product cartesian:

```
Table1
f1  f2
----------
a   1
b   4
c   5

Table2
f3  f4
----------
a   aa
b   cc

f1  f2  f3  f4
--------------------------
a   1   a   aa
a   1   b   cc
b   4   a   aa
b   4   b   cc
c   5   

Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON f1 = f3

a   1   a   aa
b   4   b   cc
c   5

Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON f1 = f3
a   1   a   aa
b   4   b   cc
```

There are a good example at wikypedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: I saw one "builder" instead of "bilder" and one e missing on adempiere, but either way it returns: Query failed: ERROR: column w_homepage_image.w_hompage_package_id does not exist LINE 4: ...mage ON adempiere.w_homepage_package.sequence = adempiere.... ^ in

Comment: Still 2 typos (adempier, hompage) but it works now. I will try to understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sub queries or joins. You can join three tables on a relative column, or nest them until reaching the first table.

```
SELECT w_bildurl 
FROM adempiere.w_bilder 
WHERE w_bilder_id = 
      (SELECT w_bilder_id 
      FROM adempiere.w_homepage_image 
      WHERE w_homepage_package_id IN 
           (SELECT sequence,  
           w_homepage_package_id                            
           FROM adempiere.w_homepage_package
           WHERE sequence > 0
           ORDER BY sequence ASC)
     LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, play with join if required.

```
SELECT 
    whp.sequence, 
    whp.w_homepage_package_id 
FROM 
    adempiere.w_homepage_package as whp
    NATURAL JOIN 
        adempiere.w_homepage_image as whi
    NATURAL JOIN 
        adempiere.w_builder as wbr
WHERE 
    whp.sequence > 0
ORDER BY whp.sequence ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JOIN keyword, it should make your life easier.

Check it here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

**it shoud be work fine**

```
$res =  "SELECT A.*, B.w_bilder_id, C.w_bildurl FROM w_homepage_package A, w_homepage_image B,w_bilder C WHERE A.sequence>O  AND B.w_homepage_package_id=A.sequence AND C.w_bildurl=B.w_bilder_id ORDER BY A.sequence ASC"; 
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $res); 
while ($promo = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
{

}
```

Comment: Do I have to substitute A, B and C for something to make this work?